# Не запускается эмулятор в Android-Studio. No emulators are currently running

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор

Я удаляла и снова закачивала SDK, заново создала эмулятор, но все равно он его не запускает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: я удалил картинку, потому что на ней никакой полезной для вопроса информации

Comment: No emulators are currently running - больше похоже на попытку запустить проект в эмуляторе пока он не стартовал. Из самого менеджера эмуляторов он запускает при [нажатии на пуск, png](https://tunecom.ru/uploads/posts/2019-10/1571316765_2019-10-17_143755.png)?